# How to reset a storyboard with page cache enabled?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using a storyboard to change the `opacity` of a Rectangle object from 1 to 0. The Storyboard works perfectly using the following codebehind:

```
StoryboardFadeHider.Begin();
```

My page is using `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` to cache the page state. The animation is started in `OnNavigatedTo` but has a delayed `BeginTime`. When loading the page for the first time, this works perfectly as the Opacity is 1 and fades to 0. When loading the page from cache, the opacity is 0 because the storyboard run already. The result in this case is

1. Opacity is 0
2. Delay
3. Storyboard starts and sets Opacity to 1
4. fade to 0.

Setting the Opacity to 1 with `FadeHider.Opacity = 1;` before running the storyboard doesn't work somehow, my guess is that the cached storyboard overrides this.

This is the storyboard and Rectangle:

```
<Page.Resources>
     <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardFadeHider">
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FadeHider" BeginTime="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
     </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
...
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Name="FadeHider" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" />
```

How can i set the opacity to 1 everytime the page is loaded before running the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to other page reset the opacity to 1 in `OnNavigatingFrom`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
  StoryboardFadeHider.Stop();
}
```

Also in `OnNavigatedTo`you can start the storyboard again :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  StoryboardFadeHider.Begin();
}
```

Comment: This has the same effect as setting the opacity to 1 before starting the storyboard. Somehow it is ignored and still 0. My guess is that the storyboard sets it to 0 again.

Comment: try to stop the storyboard

Comment: `StoryboardFadeHider.Stop();` did the trick! Stop() resets to the beginning so `FadeHider.Opacity = 1;` and `StoryboardFadeHider.SetValue(FadeHider, 1);` is not needed.